# Why does Jquery GET request return no data?

Tags: php, jquery, greasemonkey

```
$.get("http://localhost/code.php", function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

code.php:

```
<?php
echo "hello!";
?>
```

I also tried other variants with post and ajax, nothing works. I can run php scripts just fine, I can write to a file for example, however they return no data.

I'm running the scripts on a IIS server.

[EDIT]

I forgot to add an important detail, I'm calling the php script from a greasemonkey script. I tried it on the server and it works. But I need this for greasemonkey.

Comment: So if you go to http://localhost/code.php, what do you see? Also, I assume you are calling that from a page served from http://localhost/ as well, right?

Comment: And what does your JS console say? Any errors?

Comment: What about your server logs? Can you confirm it is receiving the requests?

Comment: Browser dev tools have a "Network" tab where you can see which requests are made and what's inside the response...

Comment: My apologies for the short answear. I removed it and place it in a comment. Thank you! Here it is: I placed your code in the right context and works fine with me!`<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.get("http://localhost/code.php", function(data){
alert(data);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I gave up on greasemonkey since it would not work whatever I tried. So I got scriptish and as luck would have it, the code I needed was just another click away from the addon page. So here it is if anyone else needs it:

```
var ret = GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost/code.php",
  onload: function(res) {
    alert(res.responseText);
  }
});
```

It works right away in scriptish, no need to include anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you call methods from a remote page through GreaseMonkey`, the prefix`unsafeWindow.` has to be added:

```
unsafeWindow.$.get("http://localhost/code.php", function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

If you don't need JQuery-specific methods, I recommend using [`GM_xmlhttpRequest`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest):

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    "method": "get",
    "url": "http://localhost/code.php",
    "onload": function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [this blog post](http://ryangreenberg.com/archives/2010/03/greasemonkey_jquery.php), Greasemonkey does not offer the XHR object used by jQuery, so you have to wrap what it does offer and setup the jQuery AJAX with custom implementation.

I will quote here the relevant code:

```
// Wrapper for GM_xmlhttpRequest
function GM_XHR() {
    this.type = null;
    this.url = null;
    this.async = null;
    this.username = null;
    this.password = null;
    this.status = null;
    this.headers = {};
    this.readyState = null;

    this.open = function(type, url, async, username, password) {
        this.type = type ? type : null;
        this.url = url ? url : null;
        this.async = async ? async : null;
        this.username = username ? username : null;
        this.password = password ? password : null;
        this.readyState = 1;
    };

    this.setRequestHeader = function(name, value) {
        this.headers[name] = value;
    };

    this.abort = function() {
        this.readyState = 0;
    };

    this.getResponseHeader = function(name) {
        return this.headers[name];
    };

    this.send = function(data) {
        this.data = data;
        var that = this;
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            method: this.type,
            url: this.url,
            headers: this.headers,
            data: this.data,
            onload: function(rsp) {
                // Populate wrapper object with returned data
                for (k in rsp) {
                    that[k] = rsp[k];
                }
            },
            onerror: function(rsp) {
                for (k in rsp) {
                    that[k] = rsp[k];
                }
            },
            onreadystatechange: function(rsp) {
                for (k in rsp) {
                    that[k] = rsp[k];
                }
            }
        });
    };
};
```

And to setup the AJAX of jQuery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhr: function(){return new GM_XHR;}
});
```

After this step, the `.get()` and other AJAX methods should work fine.